# How to model symmetrical function for regression using tensorflow neural network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to make regression model for symmetrical input, hoping to model function with f(x,y)=f(y,x)=F. Suddenly, i found that trained neural network will give different outputs for f(x,y) and f(y,x).

I am using dense neural network with multiple layers with Adagrad for learning on entire training set.

The part of the problem occurs because of random (non-symmetrical) weights initialization.

But it looks like making symmetrical weights on each neuron will lose benefits of using DNN.

Is it possible to solve this with DNN or what is the way to do this

example:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import pathlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

print(tf.__version__)

train = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
labels = pd.DataFrame([[0], [1], [1], [3]])



def build_model4():
  model4 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.elu, input_shape=(2,)),
    layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.elu),
    layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.elu),
    layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
  ])



  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.05, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)

  model4.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
  return model4




model4 = build_model4()
model4.summary()


EPOCHS = 500

history = model4.fit(
  train, labels,  epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=4, verbose=0)

hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
hist['epoch'] = history.epoch
hist.tail()
plt.plot(history.history['mean_squared_error'], label='train')

test=pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 1]])
o=model4.predict(test)
print(o)
```

Comment: Did you use both `[x, y, f(x,y)]` and '[x, y, f(y, x)]' as your training set or only x, y f(x,y) ?

Comment: x and y are inputs, f(x,y) should be output. F is label.

Comment: Do you have any code? It would be easier to provide help with a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your model is inherently asymmetrical, there is a simple way to force symmetry explicitly:

`g(x, y) = g(y, x) = 1/2 * (f(x, y) + f(y, x))`

Comment: i found how to apply this idea in neural network:
i used network as block, used (x,y) and (y,x) as separate inputs then i added average layer